# Conditional probability of 2 red marbles being selected

Tags: probability

Suppose a bag exactly 5 marbles that are either red or green, and the probability of the bag containing 0, 1, 2,...,5 red marbles is uniform (e.g., each has probability 1/6). One person draws a marble from the bag, and it is green. If this green marble is not put back into the bag, what is the probability that the next marble will be red?

I think this is a routine Bayes rule question. If A is the event that the next marble is red and B is the event that the first marble was green, I have:

$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(B | A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

However, I'm not quite sure this makes sense, since B|A means that the first marble being green somehow depends on the second marble being red, which is silly because the first draw can't be impacted by the second draw because that would violate temporality. Can someone please help me figure out how to solve this problem?

Comment: First draw *probabilities* can certainly be affected by later information. If I draw two cards in a row and the second is the Queen of Hearts, I can say definitely the first was not.

Comment: And you have a perfectly fine start to a calculation. For no good reason I would prefer to write the conditional probability as $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Comment: Ok, so if the 1st wasn't red, then there can't be 5 red marbles (but there could be 0-4 still). Does that mean P(B|A) = 4/5?

Comment: As I wrote, I prefer to find $\Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)$. For the probability of $A\cap B$, there are $6$ cases, each with probability $1/5$. If $0$ red, probability is $0$. If $1$ red, probability is $(1/5)(4/4)$. If $2$ red probability is $(2/5)(3/4)$, and so on. So the probability of $A\cap B$ is $(1/5)(0)+(1/5)(1/5)(4/4)+(1/5)(2/5)(3/4)+\cdots$. The probability of $B$ is computed similarly, but the calculation can be made simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose a bag exactly 5 marbles that are either red or green, and the probability of the bag containing 0, 1, 2,...,5 red marbles is uniform (e.g., each has probability 1/6). One person draws a marble from the bag, and it is green. If this green marble is not put back into the bag, what is the probability that the next marble will be red?

You have, for $N_R$ the number of red marbles in the bag: $\mathsf P(N_R=r) = \begin{cases}\frac 1 6 & : r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\} \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

For any given value of $N_R=r$, we have:

- The probability of drawing a green on the first turn: $\mathsf P(G_1\mid N_R=r) = \frac{5-r}{5}$
- The probability of drawing a green and then a red: $\mathsf P(G_1\cap R_2\mid N_R=r) = \frac{(5-r)r}{5\times 4}$

Then use the Law of Total Probability to obtain the probability of drawing a green: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(G_1) & = \sum_{r=0}^5 \mathsf P(G_1\mid N_R=r)\mathsf P(N_R=r)
\\ & = \ldots
\end{align}$$

Similarly the probability of drawing a green, and then a red on the next turn is:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(G_1 \cap R_2) & = \sum_{r=0}^5 \mathsf P(G_1\cap R_2\mid N_R=r)\mathsf P(N_R=r)
\\ & = \ldots
\end{align}$$

So the conditional probability is: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(R_2\mid G_1) & =\frac{\mathsf P(G_1\cap R_2)}{\mathsf P(G_1)} 
\\ & = \ldots
\end{align}$$

Can you complete?